# A question about the differential equation $x^2 y' -2xy = 3y^4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve the differential equation

$$x^2 y' -2xy = 3y^4$$

by letting

$$y = ux$$

And I get

$$(ux)' = 2u + 3u^4 x^2$$

$$\Rightarrow u'x = u + 3u^4 x^2$$

But I don't know how to continue.

Can someone give me some hint on how to continue or on another method to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
By observing that $x^2y' - 2xy = x^2 y' - (x^2)'y$, then we think about $\left(  
 \frac{y}{x^2}\right)'$. Let's define $z = \frac{y}{x^2}$, then:

$$\begin{align}
\implies z' = \left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)' = 3\frac{y^4}{x^4} = 3x^4 \left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)^4=3x^4 z^4 &\iff \frac{z'}{z^4} = 3x^4\\
&\iff \int \frac{dz}{z^4} = \int 3x^4dx\\
&\iff \color{red}{ -\frac{1}{3z^3} = \frac{3}{5}x^5 + C} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

From $(1)$, you deduce easily the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The substitution you tried is good for homogeneous equations, but the equation is not such. It is so called Bernoulli equation:
$$y' + a(x)y = b(x)y^n, \: n\ne 1$$
The common idea is to divide it by $y^n$ and then use the following substitution $z=y^{-(n-1)}$. So at first, let's divide both sides by $x^2$:
$$y' - \frac{2y}{x} = \frac{3y^4}{x^2}$$
Then divide by $y^4$:
$$\frac{y'}{y^4} - \frac{2}{xy^3} = \frac{3}{x^2}$$
$$\underbrace{-\frac{3y'}{y^4}}_{3(y^{-3})'} + \frac{6}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{y^3} = -\frac{9}{x^2}$$
Now you can solve it using linear ODE techniques.

Answer (score 3):

**IDEA**

Divide by y^4
$$x^2 y'y^{-4} -2xy^{-3} = 3
$$
Let : $y_1:=y^{-3}$

therfore :
$$-\frac{1}{3}y_1' x^2-2xy_1=3
$$